# Submit in Angular form

Tags: angular, forms, events, form-submit

I am working on Angular 7 forms. I made a whole form with all fields and just added a simple button at the end of this form and now I am wondering how the click on this button is firing the submit action. I have not even set the attribute type="submit" for this button. I have

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)"
```

at the top of my form. Can someone make me understand how any random button is firing this  submit functionality.
Thanks already.

P.S. I am using Material Design controls in this form.

Comment: If you can give us some more code (like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ), it would be a lot easier to help you. E.g. showing your exact HTML for the button would also be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `submit` is just a form event, which can be fired using a button with `type="submit"` *inside the form element*. This functionality is simply provided by HTML, it's not Angular specific.

Answer (score 4):

`button` in html has two types - `submit` and `button`. If you have a form and inside it a  button which type is `submit`, clicking it will force the form to submit. So if you don't want to submit, you need to change the type of your button to `button`.

```
<button mat-button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Save and Next</button>
```

Comment: So, by default a button inside a form is of submit type. Thanks @Suren for this simple and easy to understand answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not declared button type then most browsers by default `type` of `button` is `submit`  .
Suppose you have create button like
`<button name="Save">Save</button>` its by default button type is `submit`.
so that's why you are able to fire submit event within `form` tag

> In IE8 Standards mode, the default value is submit. In other compatibility modes and earlier versions of Windows Internet Explorer, the default value is button.